# To clear bits from i through 0 - bit manipulation

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

I was going to Cracking the Coding Interview chapter 5 Bit manipulation
and found way to clear bits from i through 0 in number num

```
int mask = ~(-1 >>> (31 - i));
return num & mask
```

Though the above works

Can we make it simple like

```
int mask = (-1 << (i+1));
return num & mask;
```

Am I missing any corner cases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely.  Your mask `-1 << (i+1)` is logically equivalent to the book's mask `~(-1 >>> (31 - i))`.

Your method bit-wise shifts `-1` to the left `i + 1` times, filling the lowest `i + 1` bits with `0`.

The book's method logically shifts `-1` to the right `31 - i` times, filling the highest `31 - i` bits with `0`.  However, it then inverts the bits, which is what makes yours equivalent to it.  To verify it for all values of `int`, you can create a simple for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
    System.out.println(~(-1 >>> (31 - i)) + " " + (-1 << (i+1)));
}
```

When running it, you'll see that both masks are equivalent at every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed an edge case: for `i = 31`, `(-1 << (i+1)) = -1` while `~(-1 >>> (31 - i)) = 0`.

This happens because shift counts are taken modulo the size (in bits) of the type, in this case 32, `(31 + 1) mod 32 = 0` so in both expressions the effective shift count is zero. They then act differently because of the inverted logic of the second expression.

However, `~(-1 >>> (31 - i))` *is* equivalent to the simpler `-2 << i`.